# How to Remove Duplicate with precedence of a particular field in mysql select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, duplicates

I've a mysql query which returns few records with duplicates. I need to get the unique record when both "Success" and "Error" exist in mysql result set and it should consider only "Success" as precedence. In below example - Job name "Timothy Plan Global CrRd" has two records - Success and Error. I need to get only Success one. I tried with group by clause on job_name but it only picks up Error one in result set. But I want the status with success one as precedence. Can you please help?

Here is the query -

```
select status as 'Status', job_logid as 'Job Log ID', job_name as 'Job Name', job_type as 'Job Type', file_name as 'File Name', start_time as 'Run Date/Time', run_user as 'Run User' from etp.job_log
where DATE(start_time) = Date(now())-1 and job_type = 'Outbound'
and job_name like '%CrRd%'
order by job_name;
```

[image]

Here is the correct query by David. Thank you.

```
select max(status) as 'Status', job_logid as 'Job Log ID', job_name as 'Job Name', job_type as 'Job Type', file_name as 'File Name', start_time as 'Run Date/Time', run_user as 'Run User' from etp.job_log
where DATE(start_time) = Date(now())-1 and job_type = 'Outbound'
and job_name like '%CrRd%'
group by job_name
```

Comment: In this case, will the "success" always occur after "error"?

Comment: Not always! But if Success happens after Error then it will take only Success one, otherwise it should show only Error.

Comment: > `But if Success happens after Error then it will take only Success one, otherwise it should show only Error` so do you only want the latest row?

Comment: I've to agree -- that may do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using select `select max(status) as 'Status'`, that could do the job of getting first the status 'Success'. Then we can use `group by job_logid,job_name` to preserve the duplicates from the one that doesnt have an error and avoid to select the ones that have an error after o before a Success status.

Comment: Yes David. That's correct answer. We don't need to group by with Job_logid, only job_name is sufficient. Here is the query I tested - select max(status) as 'Status', job_logid as 'Job Log ID', job_name as 'Job Name', job_type as 'Job Type', file_name as 'File Name', start_time as 'Run Date/Time', run_user as 'Run User' from etp.job_log
where DATE(start_time) = Date(now())-1 and job_type = 'Outbound'
and job_name like '%CrRd%'
group by job_name